# rsync to server and set ownership and permissions, use sudo

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, sudo

I have a server with a website, /var/www/html/website.

I use rsync to transfer updated files over:

`rsync -avzu --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --chown=user:www-data --progress /mnt/c/xampp7/htdocs/wbsite/ user@8.8.8.8:/var/www/html/website`

`--chown=user:www-data` doesn't work because I need to use sudo.

I've added to sudoers the following line:

`user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod, /bin/chown, /bin/chgrp`

But if I try

`ssh user@8.8.8.8 "sudo find /var/www/html/website -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +"`

I get `sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`

I need to automate this so typing the password is a no and as much as I'd like to use git, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

That sudoers entry allows you to run `/bin/chmod` with `sudo`, but you're trying to use `sudo` on the entire `find` command, so it doesn't apply. So use `sudo` on just `/bin/chmod` *inside* the `-exec`:

```
ssh user@8.8.8.8 "find /var/www/html/website -type f -exec sudo /bin/chmod 664 {} +"
```

Answer (score -1):

Then you need to add `user` to the sudoers list on 8.8.8.8 to allow it to elevate permissions without using a password for the command `find`.

Alternatively, copy the pub key from `user` into `.ssh/authorized_keys` on `8.8.8.8` & just call `find...` without the `sudo command`.

Comment: The user is already in the sudoers list as mentioned right in the middle of my question

Comment: copying the pub key from user into .ssh/authorized_keys on 8.8.8.8 won't allow me to execute find without sudo, it just allows me to login using the private key, which I can already do, that has nothing to do with executing a command using sudo AFAIK